# Convert ImageSource to Bitmap Image

Tags: type-conversion

I am having following code in a wpf project:

```
    private ImageSource _videoStream;
    public ImageSource VideoStream
    {
        get => _videoStream;
    }
```

The problem is that I need to have instead of an ImageSource a Bitmap image. Therefore I changed the above code to:

```
private Bitmap _videoStream;
    public Bitmap VideoStream
    {
        get => (Bitmap)_videoStream;
    }
```

This throws following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. Bitmap:'System.Drawing.Bitmap' BindingExpression:Path=VideoStream; DataItem='ViewCamViewModel' (HashCode=20869327); target element is 'ImageWithOverlayControl' (Name=''); target property is 'VideoStream' (type 'ImageSource')
```

What is the correct conversion method here? Can I use a "**ImageSourceConverter**"? If yes, how does it work?

thanks